# Popup Never Closes

Tags: wpf, popup

WPF is really getting me out of my nerves here. I configured a popup with some complex content (grid, buttons etc..). I set its StaysOpen property to False and IsOpen to True on a textbox MouseDown preview event.

Ths thing is that it opens but never closes when clicking anywhere outside the window.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

My popup has buttons inside. When I click one of those, the popup closes when I click outside of it. Is some weird stuff happening to the events routing?

Comment: have you tried it closing manually like do you have any close button on it? or map a key like ESC key to esc the popup.

Comment: I can do it like that.. but I need it to close automatically when losing focus.

Comment: Can you add simple XAML that demonstrate this problem (may help you debugging as well)?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I am using PHP SSDK for FB Login. The popup is not closed after successful authentication from FB. My Site is opening in the same popup.

I need to know how to use redirect and cancel url in FB login connect and how to refresh the parent window after login.

Thanks in advance. Umar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the popup won't close if opened by any other control event. I just binded the IsOpen property to the IsChecked property of a ToggleButton to simulate a combobox.

Thanks for all your answers.

Comment: I concur, same thing worked for me.  Strange behavior, but worked.  Created a binding for the IsOpenProperty in code to a toggle button IsChecked property and it worked fine.  Ill take it :)

Answer (score 1):

I was also having this issue, except on the PreviewMouseButtonUp event of a Button.  The assumption that there is some bug with Popups and trying to open them in Tunneling events was accurate and led me down the path to my fix (which is a little more generic).

I needed to resolve this (the host control was generic / could be several types of controls) by listening for the bubbling event instead of the tunneling event, specifically with the [AddHandler(RoutedEvent,Delegate,Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms598899%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method in order to capture handled events.

WAG the issue lies somewhere when transitioning from tunneling to bubbling.

Answer (score 1):

I use code behind to initialize popup, and I've found that it's not closed if ran sync from other UI action like mouse event. To workaround this I run it async:

```
    public static void ShowPopupMessage(string message)
    {
        DispatcherHelper.UIDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            var popup = new Popup
            {
                Child = new AutoHideMessage(message),
                StaysOpen = false,
                IsOpen = true
            };
        }));
    }
```

Comment: This solution appears to work me, and agree this also seems to occur only if opened from certain UI events like `MouseUp`.  I think the popup might never be getting focus, hence there is never a lost focus event to close it.

Answer (score 0):

> I set IsOpen on a textbox MouseDown preview event.

Set it to what? And where is the TextBox hosted?

I can only guess with the scant information provided, but I'd say when you click outside the `Popup`, your event handler is firing and opening it up again.

Comment: The textbox is inside an user control that is used in a Window. In the user control I'm setting IsOpen = true whenever the textbox is clicked. When the popup loses focus it never closes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LostFocus` event of the PopUp. If the focus is not within the popup, set its `IsOpen` to false to close it.

Comment: It does nothing. If I start the window with the popup IsOpen property set to true it works normally. If I set it on the textbox PreviewMouseButtonDown event it does not work.